# AWS CloudWatch logs group naming convention

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-code-deploy

I have to send logs from AWS EC2 server to the AWS CloudWatch logs. For this, I have created a CloudWatch configuration file for collecting logs such as

```
{
    "agent": {
            "run_as_user": "root"
    },
    "logs": {
            "logs_collected": {
                    "files": {
                            "collect_list": [
                                    {
                                            "file_path": "/var/log/testing.log",
                                            "log_group_name": "/project/development",
                                            "log_stream_name": "{instance_id}_testing-logs"
                                    }
                            ]
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

I have created an application in AWS CodeDeploy named `project` with three groups inside that namely `development`, `staging`, and `production`. I want CloudWatch to use the naming convention such as `/project/development` and similarly to name it for `staging` and `production` to name its log group `log_group_name`. For this, I do not want to create three separate files for each environment.

Is there any CloudWatch variable available for CodeDeploy which I can use it to name `log_group_name` like there are naming variables available for `{instance_id}` which automatically picks the Instance Id.

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [CloudWatch Agent Configuration File: Logs Section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html#CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Logssection) documentation. For either the `log_group_name` or `log_stream_name` field,

> as part of the name, you can use `{instance_id}`, `{hostname}`, `{local_hostname}`, and `{ip_address}` as variables within the name.

If you want to use CodeDeploy specific variables in your CloudWatch Logs name, CodeDeploy do make [available a set of environment variables for hook scripts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-structure-hooks.html#reference-appspec-file-structure-environment-variable-availability). So the idea is to do a CodeDeploy deployment of your CloudWatch agent installation and create your CloudWatch agent configuration file using the CodeDeploy variables.

Comment: I know that I can use only four of the variables available above. But is there any way to set the name of the log group according to the CodeDeploy such as `/<codedeploy-application-name>/<codedeploy-group-name>`  or I have to create three separate config files?

Answer (score 0):

> **log_stream_name**
>   Specifies the destination log stream. You can use a literal string or predefined variables ({instance_id}, {hostname}, {ip_address}), or combination of both to define a log stream name. A log stream is created automatically if it doesn't already exist.

CloudWatch logs can only access those variables above.

Take a read of the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) to see more details.

Comment: Other than those four variables is there any variables available for CodeDeploy naming such as `/<codedeploy-application-name>/<codedeploy-group-name>`. Or should I create 3 separate config files?

Comment: Hi,

No these are not supported unfortunately, you'll need 3 seperate config items :(